# Plain installation of current version of Wekan on Ubuntu?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm, kanban

[Wekan](https://wekan.github.io/) is an open-source [Kanban Board](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanban_board) which used to be easy to install using nodejs (given that you already set up your MongoDB). I am stumbling upon the actual installation steps of [the guide to install Wekan on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/ubuntu-wekan-installation/):

> Download the latest version wekan source code using the wget command and extract it.
>
> `wget https://github.com/wekan/wekan/releases/download/v0.63/wekan-0.63.tar.gz`
>
> `tar xf wekan-0.63.tar.gz`
>
> And you will get a new directory named `bundle`. Go to that directory and install the Wekan dependencies using the npm command as shown below.
>
> `cd bundle/programs/server`
>
> `npm install`

Figuring out the [last stable version](https://github.com/wekan/wekan/releases) is easy, there are new stable versions nearly every day (as of March 2019), which somehow seem to contradict the [common definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle).

More importantly, the directory `bundle/programs/server` does not exist, only `server`, but it does not contain a `main.js` which would be necessary to run

```
node main.js
```

**Other resources considered:**

I did of course check the [official documentation](https://github.com/wekan/wekan/wiki/Platforms), but it looks not up-to-date. The page `https://github.com/wekan/wekan/wiki/Install-and-Update` is redirecting to a rather untidy page which does no longer talk about a standalone installation.

I prefer a minimal installation and **not** a solution using `snap` like described at [computingforgeeks](https://computingforgeeks.com/install-wekan-kanban-board-system-ubuntu-18-04/)

There is also an unanswered question about a more specific installation around: [Installing Wekan via Sandstorm on cPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52981085/installing-wekan-via-sandstorm-on-cpanel) which follows a similar approach.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-wekan-open-source-kanban-on-ubuntu-16-04 is also very close to the guide I tried to follow.

Comment: Did you check their `rebuild-wekan.sh`? It works only from within a git repository, so use `git clone`

Comment: Yeah, I tried understanding that, but it throws quite a lot of errors plus it is not as minimal as I wanted it to be.

Comment: I would already be happy if somebody could guide me through the `rebuild-wekan.sh` script.

Comment: Or some guidance how to proceed if https://github.com/wekan/wekan-autoinstall fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest releases on the Wekan page are actually no ready-to-use node builds.

Wekan is built using [Meteor](https://meteor.com) and you will need Meteor to create the build. This is because you could also build it using Meteor against other architectures than `os.linux.x86_64`.

So here is how to build the [latest release as of today](https://github.com/wekan/wekan/releases/tag/v2.48) on your dev-machine to then deploy it:

#### Build it yourself

[1.] Install [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/install)

```bash
 curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
```

[2.] Download and extract the latest Wekan

```bash
wget https://github.com/wekan/wekan/archive/v2.48.tar.gz
tar xf wekan-2.48.tar.gz
cd wekan-2.48
```

[3.] Install Wekan Dependencies

```bash
./rebuild-wekan.sh 
# use option 1
```

[4.] Install dependency Meteor packages

Now it gets dirty. Somehow the required packages are not included in the release (an issue should be opened at GH). You need to install them yourself:

```bash
# create packages dir
mkdir -p packages
cd packages
# clone packages
git clone git@github.com:wekan/wekan-ldap.git
git clone git@github.com:wekan/meteor-accounts-cas.git
git clone git@github.com:wekan/wekan-scrollbar.git
# install repo and extract packages
git clone git@github.com:wekan/meteor-accounts-oidc.git
mv meteor-accounts-oidc/packages/switch_accounts-oidc ./
mv meteor-accounts-oidc/packages/switch_oidc ./
rm -rf meteor-accounts-oidc/
cd ../
```

[5.] Build against your architecure

```bash
meteor build ../build --architecute os.linux.x86_64
# go grab a coffee... yes even with nvme SSD...
```

Once the build is ready you can go `../build` and check out the `wekan-2.48.tar.gz` which now contains your built bundle including the described folders and files.

Use this bundle to deploy as described in the documentation.

#### Summary

This describes only how to create the build yourself and I am not giving any guarantee that the build package will run when deployed to your target environment.

I think there is either some issue with the way the releases are attached on GH or they explicitly want to keep it open against which arch you want to build.

In any case I would open an issue with demand for a more clear documentation and a description for reproduction of the errors your mentioned.

#### Further readings

https://guide.meteor.com/deployment.html#custom-deployment